# Template loader doesn't find /registration/password_reset_form.html

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I am having a strange issue using the built in **password_rest view** of django(1.8). In the documentation they say that the template name defaults to **registration/password_reset_form.html**. Keeping that in mind, I didn't give any template name in my **urls.py**, thinking that django will load the default template.Here is my url for the password reset

urls.py

```
url(r'^password_reset$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
```

When I click the forgot password link,

```
<p><a href={% url 'password_reset' %}> Forgot your password?</a></p>
```

which executes the password_rest view, I am getting Template DoesNotExist error and below is the error message

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/password_reset
registration/password_reset.html

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/vinothkumar/github/djtest/templates/registration/password_reset.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/home/vinothkumar/github/djtest/venv_new/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset.html (File does not exist)
/home/vinothkumar/github/djtest/venv_new/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration/password_reset.html (File does not exist)
/home/vinothkumar/github/djtest/accounts/templates/registration/password_reset.html (File does not exist)
```

my question is why the template loader is looking for **/registration/password_reset.html** instead of loading the default **/registration/password_reset_form.html**?

I tried the same approach for **password_reset_done**, in this case it loads the default template **/registration/password_reset_done.html**. and everything there works fine.

Comment: Perhaps `/accounts/password_reset` is matching a different URL pattern that does use `/registration/password_reset_form.htm`.

Comment: Can you supply your `settings.py`

Comment: Hi Artern Thanks for your comment. Here is my templates section of the settings file

Comment: `TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
 `